# Comparing two comma delimited strings

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 strings `str1`: `'abc,def,ghi'` and `str2`: `'tyu,abc,fgh'`.

I want to compare these two strings using the delimiter `,`. Now since the 2 strings have `abc` it should return true. I want a function in Oracle SQL which can perform this operation.

Comment: You can split the delimited string into rows and then compare. See [**Split comma delimited strings in a table in Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 2):

Looks complicated but it is just a couple of helper functions to split a list into separate values (to be contained into a table type) and then a very simple function to test the intersection of two collections.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2s_Table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE FUNCTION regexp_escape(
  expression VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN REGEXP_REPLACE( expression, '([$^[()+*?{\|])', '\\\1', 1, 0, 'c' );
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION splitList(
  list  VARCHAR2,
  delim VARCHAR2 := ','
) RETURN VARCHAR2s_Table DETERMINISTIC
AS
  pattern   VARCHAR2(256);
  len       BINARY_INTEGER;
  t_items   VARCHAR2s_Table := VARCHAR2s_Table();
BEGIN
  IF list IS NULL THEN
    NULL;
  ELSIF delim IS NULL THEN
    t_items.EXTEND( LENGTH( list ) );
    FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH( list ) LOOP
      t_items(i) := SUBSTR( list, i, 1 );
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    pattern   := '(.*?)($|' || REGEXP_ESCAPE( delim ) || ')';
    len       := REGEXP_COUNT( list, pattern ) - 1;
    t_items.EXTEND( len );
    IF len = 1 THEN
      t_items(1) := list;
    ELSE
      FOR i IN 1 .. len LOOP
        t_items(i) := REGEXP_SUBSTR( list, pattern, 1, i, NULL, 1 );
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN t_items;
END;
/

CREATE FUNCTION check_list_intersect(
  list1 VARCHAR2,
  list2 VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  IF splitList( list1 ) MULTISET INTERSECT splitList( list2 ) IS EMPTY THEN
    RETURN 0;
  ELSE
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT check_list_intersect( 'abc,def,ghi', 'abc' ) AS matches
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Results**:

```
 MATCHES
---------
       1
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT check_list_intersect( 'abc,def,ghi', 'abcd' ) AS matches
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Results**:

```
 MATCHES
---------
       0
```

Comment: This is what I call "full pl/sql solution". Nice done.

Answer (score 1):

The below will make the trick.

```
with temp as  (
       select 1 strid, 'abc,def,ghi' Error  from dual
       union all
       select 2, 'tyu,abc,fgh'  from dual
     )
select str 
from (
     SELECT  strid, trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level)) str
     FROM (SELECT strid, Error str FROM temp) t
     CONNECT BY instr(str, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0 
     )
group by str 
having count(distinct strid) > 1;
```

Comment: this it is nice that is more sql-istic, using sql engine to compare things.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: This answer is not fully correct.** (See the comments.)

Starting from dcieslak answer(csv split with regexp), a variation of the subject would be:

```
create or replace function check_string_intersec(str1 varchar2, str2 varchar2) return number 
is
begin
   for k in (SELECT  trim(regexp_substr(str1, '[^,]+', 1, level)) item
             FROM dual
             CONNECT BY instr(str1, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0 
             )
   loop
       if instr(str2, k.item,1) > 0 then return 1; end if;
   end loop;
   return 0;
end;
```

This splits first string and search for every item in the second string.

Comment: is there any predefinrd function that can perform this action?

Comment: almost sure NO. It is to custom/localized to be implemented in a library.

Comment: `check_string_intersec( 'abc,def,ghi', 'abcd' )` The second string does not have an `abc` item so the function should return `0` but `INSTR` will find a match.

Comment: Try this: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_string_intersec( str1 VARCHAR2, str2 VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS TYPE VTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000); l1 VTable; pattern CONSTANT CHAR(5) := '[^,]+'; BEGIN SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( str1, pattern, 1, LEVEL ) BULK COLLECT INTO l1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( str1, pattern ); FOR k IN ( SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( str2, pattern, 1, LEVEL ) item FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( str2, pattern ) ) LOOP IF k.item MEMBER OF l1 THEN RETURN 1; END IF; END LOOP; RETURN 0; END; /`

Comment: Thanks, but: 1. it wasn't my intent 2. It would be too similar to your answer and... 3. I want to keep the answer as an example of 'partial solution'(I could/can delete it anytime).